# How can I compare two folders (not files) using VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Xcode has a feature that allows you to compare and visualize folders / files and their indexes, I'm unable to find to a similar functionality in VScode (other than comparing files side by side).

Xcode pops up a small menu that shows you for example

Project 1: Folder A
Project 2: Folder A, Folder B

and you can click on each one to see each of their differences.

Attached is an example of how I could manually/visually check for differences and it's cumbersome as they're placed vertically rather than side by side.

[image]

Comment: There's an [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=moshfeu.compare-folders) but no idea how good/safe it is.

Comment: I was hoping for something that's already built in to avoid security threats.

Comment: Agree it would be a useful feature. Amazing how this is not a standard feature of all programmer IDEs. You might investigate options to raise a feature request at VS Code's GitHub repo.

Comment: Comparing folders is not en essential feature of IDEs, however you wanted it. Microsoft does not have that for VS for Windows/Mac, so naturally VSCode has no such feature. It's also weird that you are attempting to compare two versions in two folders without putting them in Git. With Git, comparing such is a lot easier.